# Add timezone to this js schedule?

Tags: javascript, html, scheduled-tasks

I have this javascript code to schedule when certain divs show, but the problem I'm having is it's not using device time or our time zone. I really need it to be assigned to the central time zone.

```
function displayMsg() {
    var currentTime = new Date();

    function toUTC(date) {
        return Date.UTC(
            date.getFullYear(),
            date.getMonth(),
            date.getDate(),
            date.getHours(),
            date.getMinutes(),
            date.getSeconds(),
            date.getMilliseconds()
        );
    }
    toUTC(currentTime);

    var startMsg1Time = new Date("2021-10-03T11:15:00Z");
    var endMsg1Time = new Date("2021-10-08T14:33:00Z");
    var startMsg2Time = new Date("2021-11-15T23:00:01Z");
    var endMsg2Time = new Date("2021-11-16T22:59:59Z");

    if (currentTime.getTime() > startMsg1Time.getTime() && currentTime.getTime() <= endMsg1Time.getTime()) {
        $('.Msg1').show();
    } else if (currentTime.getTime() > endMsg1Time.getTime) {
        $('.Msg1').hide();
    }

    if (currentTime.getTime() > startMsg2Time.getTime() && currentTime.getTime() <= endMsg2Time.getTime()) {
        $('.Msg2').show();
    } else if (currentTime.getTime() > endMsg2Time.getTime) {
        $('.Msg2').hide();
    }

}
displayMsg();
```

As a side note, this isn't completely achieving what I need. I'm trying to have a message show every Sunday from 8:30am-11:15am and Friday from 7:00pm-8:15pm. I was going to use this method and just create a schedule a month at a time, but if anyone can recommend a better approach then I'm happy to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like in below snippet , i.e , giving only minutes and hour and then checking if `day = 1 (Monday)` . I have set alarm time to `11:25 PM` to `11:35 PM`(`Monday`) (**You can set any**)

> Use update of alarm according to need , here I have set `1sec` using `setInterval`

> Below snippet is for demo only , you can have any number of messages and alarm and specify day of alarm to come up or month (and can be year to which alarm ring)

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var d = new Date();

  var Msg1Day = d.getDay();
  var Msg1TimeStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 23, 25, 0, 0)
  var Msg1TimeEnd = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 23, 35, 0, 0)

  if (Msg1Day === 1) {
    if (d >= Msg1TimeStart && d <= Msg1TimeEnd) {
      document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = "Alarm is ON"
      document.querySelector(".Msg1").innerHTML = "You already enjoyed Sunday, It's Monday Time and soon will Be Tuesday(Alarm is from 11:25 PM - 11:35 PM)"
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = "Alarm is OFF"
      document.querySelector(".Msg1").innerHTML = ""
    }
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = "Today is not monday"
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="Msg1"></div>
<div id="demo">Alaram status will be in 1sec and will be updated every second</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!

Comment: No problem , Happy to help @TylerConwell